# Can I use Azure Notification Hub for a custom push notifications service?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Azure notifications hub supports pushing notifications to various notification services (android, ios, windows phone etc).  Is it possible to define a custom notification service to push notifications to?

Comment: Simple questions, simple answer: no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Azure Notification Hubs - Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs):**](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-faq/)

> 2. Which device platforms do you support?
>
> We support sending notifications to Apple iOS, Android, Windows
>   Universal and Windows Phone, Kindle, Android China (via Baidu),
>   Xamarin (iOS & Android), Chrome Apps platforms.
>
> 3. Do you support SMS/Email/web notifications?
>
> **Notification Hubs is primarily designed to send notifications to
>   mobile apps using the above listed platforms.** We do not provide
>   capability to send email or SMS however third party platforms which
>   provide these capabilities can be integrated along with Notification
>   Hubs to send native push notifications by using Azure Mobile Services.
>   E.g. this tutorial talks about how to send SMS notifications using
>   Azure Mobile services - [Send SMS with Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/partner-twilio-mobile-services-how-to-use-voice-sms/).We also do not
>   provide an in-browser push notification out of the box. Customers may
>   choose to implement this using SignalR. We also provide a tutorial for
>   sending push notification to Chrome apps which will work on Google
>   Chrome browser. See this - [Chrome Apps tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-chrome-get-started/).